# Will extend create a new copy in Python

Tags: python

In the following code, why does `w` still hold the `5` after popping the `5` from `v`?

```
>>> w = [1,2,3]
>>> v = [4,5]
>>> w.extend(v)
>>> w
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> v
[4, 5]
>>> v.pop()
5
>>> v
[4]
>>> w
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Instead of awkwardly describing the situation, why not post the code or an interpreter session that shows us what's going on and where the output differs from what you expected?

Comment: [mcve] please. You're playing hide and seek with us.

Answer (score 2):

The `extend` method of a list, accepts an iterable (not just another list), and extends the list with all the items from the iterable.

Official Python documentation:

> Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.

This is a shorter way of manually iterating over the other iterable, and `append` them to the original list:

```
v = [1,2,3]
w = [4,5]
for i in w:
   v.append(i)
```

This means a reference to the the items are copied from the iterable to the original list, so later modifying the iterable (the list `w`) won't affect the original list (`v`).

To make it clear, this does not change mutability/immutability of the `iterable` items themselves. So if the items from `w` are mutable, they'll stay mutable after being appended to `v` (a reference is copied).

Comment: This is wrong or at least misleading. Nothing is copied when you use extend. Check for yourself by doing this example with a list of mutable objects and then mutating them by accessing only one of the lists.

Comment: In case of mutable items in the 2nd iterable, a reference to them is copied. Hence changing the mutable items, will reflect on all references. The question is about, if calling `extend` will keep any correlation with the 2nd `list` (passed to `extend`) and my answer was pointing that the answer is no, because the parameter to `extend` is not necessarily a `list` (mutable). It can be any `iterable` (say a string), so the `extend` method itself won't keep any reference to the iterable, but copies its items.

Comment: Yes, but extend does not make any difference between mutable and immutable objects. No object is ever copied when using `list.extend`. That's why I complained before you edited your post.

Comment: Correct, I updated the post to help it clear that ambiguity. Thanks for pointing that out. I did not anticipate the answer may be interpreted in that way.

Answer (score 0):

The integers 1,2,3,4,5 are *somewhere* in memory and `w` points to all of them after `w.extend(v)`. The fact that you delete the last reference from `v` via its `pop` method does not change that.

Answer (score 0):

`extend` adds object references to the list. After `w.extend(v)`, both lists have references to the items in `v`. `v.pop()` removes the reference from `v`, but its still in `w`. Once you've extended a list, additions or removals from other containers doesn't matter.... that's what reference counting is all about.